# Undefined char or int

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main()
{

    char temp[20];
    printf("Whats the temperature\n");
    scanf("%s", temp);
    if (temp >= 32 <= 39)
    {
        printf(" %s degrees! It is too hot mister cool it down buddy", temp);
    }
    else if (temp >= 19 <= 32)
    {
        printf(" %s degrees! that is quite the nice temperature", temp);
    }
    else if (temp >= 40)
    {
        printf(" %s degrees! okey buddy now its time to put on AC mister fister", temp);
    }
    else if (temp <= 18)
    {
        printf("%s degrees! That is quite chilly my friend, wanna put on a jacket maybe?", temp);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Dont know why but for some reason it doesnt matter what number i write the message %s it is too hot mister cool it down buddy
just appears

Comment: `if (temp >= 32 <= 39)` --> `if (temp >= 32 && temp <= 39)`, same for `if (temp >= 19 <= 32)`

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Comment: If you crank up your compiler warning level, you may just get a warning along the lines of "expression is always true".

Answer (score 2):

The condition `temp >= 32 <= 39` is interpreted as `(temp >= 32) <= 39`.

`temp >= 32` will become either `0` or `1` (according to the result of comparision), so they are always less than 39.

You should use `temp >= 32 && temp <= 39` instead.

Also `temp >= 19 <= 32` should be `temp >= 19 && temp <= 32`.

Finally, instead of reading the temperature as string, you should read it as integer.

```
int temp; /* char -> int, no array */
printf("Whats the temperature\n");
scanf("%d", &temp); /* %s -> %d, add & */
```

`%s`s used in `printf` should also be changed to `%d` then. You don't need to add `&` for `printf`.